# Loop picture using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circuitikz

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to make such a diagram in `TikZ`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following might be a starting point. You might want to consult the `pgfmanual`, therein is the section "5 Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs" (page 70, currently), which might be interesting for you.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    junction/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=2pt},
    math node/.style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$},
    block/.style={draw, rectangle, math node},
  ]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={anchor=center}, row sep=7mm, column sep=5mm]
    {
      |(s)| & |[junction](j1)| & |[block](c)|c & |[block](P)|P & |[block](F)|F &
        \coordinate(j2); & \coordinate(e); \\
      & & & |[block](H)|H & & & \\
    };
  \begin{scope}
    [every node/.style={above, math node}]
    \draw[->]
      (s) --node{\tilde{u}}node[at end, below left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{+} (j1);
    \draw[->] (j1) --node{\tilde{e}} (c);
    \draw[->] (c) --node{\tilde{\pi}} (P);
    \draw[->] (P) --node{y} (F);
    \draw[->] (F) --node{\hat{y}} (e);
    \draw[->] (j2) |- (H) -|node[at end, below left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{-} (j1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just mine it was  my penultimate available vote. Very good.